# Gravitational self-interaction

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, spacetime, curvature, interactions

Today, someone asked me why "the warped space-time warps itself" (he read it in [Kip Thorne's: The Science of Interstellar](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0393351378)). I guess this is related to the gravitational self-interaction. But I don't really understand the gravitational self-interaction. Why the curvature in general relativity influences itself?

Comment: Technically, because the field equations are non-linear.

Comment: So implies the non-linearity of the field equation the non-linearity of the lagrange density, which is  neeeded for the self-interaction term? Ok I accept this answer in the mathematically sense. But what is the physically interpration that the geometry influences itself? But the mass is still the cause of the curvature?

Comment: Physically, the interpretation is, that the gravitational field carries energy and all energy is a source of gravitation, although that is subtle as the stress-energy of the gravitational field is coordinate dependent (and not a proper tensor).

Comment: Why is there energy associated with the pure geometric phenomenon of GR?

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform: You wrote that there is now gravitational energy. But then there would no self-interaction? Shouldn't the gravitational enery not be included in the terms at the l.h.s of the EFE?

Comment: @SebastianRiese No it is not because of non linearity. GR is a theory of a metric and the Einstein Equation evolves the metric. Some metrics are curved. Maxwell is a linear theory of an electromagnetic field. And the Maxwell Equation says how the electromagnetic field evolves. Some electromagnetic fields are nonzero. Linearity or nonlinearity has nothing to do with it. And comments are seeking clarification, it's bad to have wrong answers get upvoted in comments because people can't edit or downvote comments.

Comment: @Timaeus I totally disagree with your analogy to electromagnetism. For me self-interaction means self-interaction. In a way, interaction means non-linearity by definition. Interacting solutions cannot be superposed, non-interacting ones can. In this sense the electromagnetic field does not influence itself: Given two vacuum solutions you can always add them, they will again be a solution. This is not true for general relativity, in this sense on could say the non-linearity *is* the self-interaction.

Comment: @Timaeus I might add, that I believe our disagreement is about words and the meaning we assign to imprecise language, not really a conceptual disagreement. You emphasize the word "influence" in the question, I got caught up on "self-interaction" in the title.

Comment: @SebastianRiese My response to your comment was mostly about the inappropriateness of answering in comments. They can't be tweaked to be corrected and they one have up votes and down votes aren't possible. A solution in GR is a while manifold, if you had a big-bang to big-crunch universe an another one with less proper time from start to finish how would you even begin to even talk about adding them? It's two different manifolds. The quote is just an everyday experience of a differential operator saying how thing change in time based on their spatial variations.

Comment: @Timaeus You can also consider GR on a single chart (+ boundary conditions) or you can require that the space be asymptotically flat and stationary, then you can, in a well defined sense, speak about adding different solutions.

Comment: @SebastianRiese I have no idea what you are aiming at going through some contortions and limiting your models just to pretend you can add, only to then say the sum isn't a solution. The coupled Maxwell-Lorentz system of charges and fields isn't linear anyway. It's the same story for both. Write your initial conditions, evolve them according to the evolution equations. The real sin here is that laypeople imagine that physics is mysterious and rather than lay the physics plain you falsely pretend they have a point, then try to explain it. And the same **exact** issues come up in electromagnetism

Answer (score 14):

There are a million ways to answer the "why" here, but here is the simplest way to see that there has to be a gravity-gravity interaction in GR:

we have two things baked into the theory:

1) locally, we can only move at the speed of light, which means that we can only travel at the speed of light, as measured by the metric tensor

2) we can transmit signals with gravitational waves

So, let's set up a gravitational field, somehow.  This will bake in some energy into the metric tensor, and create a non-trivial spacetime geometry.

Now, send a localized gravitational wave with a small energy relative to the curvature through this geometry.  It will travel, to first approximation, along a null geodesic in the background geometry.  This is a different path than it would travel in the absence of the spacetime curvature, obviously.  Well, here you go -- the gravitational field is interacting with itself.

Comment: I like how this shows there is self-interaction of the field even in a weak-field limit.

Comment: Where is the gravitational wave come from?

Comment: @Core2016: it doesn't ultimately matter -- some localized source

Comment: Ok but why is it a self-interaction of the gravitational field. More precisely why does in this case the field influence itself? Isn't this only possible if the gravitational wave cames from the same gravitational source?

Comment: @Core2016: No, this is explicitly independent of that.  The static background field actually scatters the wave that passes through it.  Gravity is influencing gravity.

Comment: But then I have two independent sources of gravity which interact. But not one which influences itselfe

Comment: @Core2016: I dont' get your objection.  The gravitational field self interacts.  And of course you can have back-reaction.

Comment: I tthougth that the statement "the warped spacetime warps itself" means there is one source of gravity which produeses curvature and the curvature carrys energy which produces more curvature? But in your example we have two sources of gravity (the source for the background field and the wave)?

Comment: @Core2016: OK.  THe things interacting are the two different gravitational fields.  The sources don't matter, int he formalism.  They don't even actually have to be present.  You can come up with examples of self-interaction, like black hole ringdown, but those are much less obviously true and don't fundamentally alter the argument.

Comment: @Zo I feel some misunderstanding going on in this comment thread. Your last comment states that there are two gravitational fields interacting. But this seems to be the exact point of confusion for OP: there is only *one* gravitational field. The wave and the background are the same field, which is interacting with itself.

Comment: @M.Winter  sure, I guess?  This quibble seems intensely pedantic to me.  Sometimes, especially when talking about self-interaction, it's easier to think of it as "a field in region A" and "a field in region B", or "background + perturbation", or whatever situation you have. It's still, fundamentally "one field", but any analysis is easier when you think of it as "two different fields with an interaction".  The second thing is the edifice on which all of QFT is built, after all.

Comment: @Zothe It is pedantic if you know this stuff already. It is crucial information if you don't. Reading this comment thread I can't help but think that you talking about two fields interacting while OP asking about a single self-interacting field (while technically equivalent) is a source for confusion. I did not want to educate you in any way (you certainly know much more than me), I just wanted to leave a comment for a future reader who is as confused about this as I have once been.

Answer (score 0):

The same thing happens in electromagnetism. And the first step in electromagnetism is to admit that the electromagnetic field exists and has particular values at every event. Then you note that an initial slice can be extended forwards or backwards by the Maxwell Equation. You can think of $$\frac{\partial \vec B}{\partial t}=-\vec \nabla\times \vec E$$ as evolving the magnetic part. And think of $$\frac{\partial \vec E}{\partial t}=\frac{1}{\epsilon_0}\left(-\vec J+\frac{1}{\mu_0}\vec \nabla\times \vec B\right)$$ as evolving the electric part.

So electromagnetic fields don't need something to force then to be nonzero, they have a particular value and they evolve in particular ways. That's exactly what happens with the metric. It has particular values. And just like Maxwell tells the electromagnetic field how to evolve, Einstein tells the metric how to evolve.

You literally can't object to Einstein and think Maxwell is fine. It's the exact same thing going on. Yes, the evolution equation is nonlinear and there are more of them (second order and for a symmetric rank two tensor). It just makes it harder to right them down, but it doesn't change what is going on.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36200/discussion-on-answer-by-timaeus-gravitational-self-interaction).

Answer (score 0):

A good example (assume e.g. black hole is accelerating and creates gravitational waves):

Step *1.* Linearize general relativity (assume that space does not warp itself)

Step *2.* Curvature creates gravitational waves

Step *3.* Gravitational waves create curvature

Step *4.* Re-do the calculation: Curvature creates gravitational waves (gravitational waves technically create gravitational waves, although the effect is miniscule)

Comment: Does a static black hole in no double star system creates gravitational waves?

Comment: @Core2016 No. And a purely radial electromagnetic field also creates no waves.

Comment: So why create curvature gravitational waves (according to 2.)?

Comment: I should  be more specific. A black hole must be accelerating to create gravitational waves.