# Does gravitational field 'attract itself'?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, terminology, interactions

In an article at the "Gravity Probe B" website,

https://einstein.stanford.edu/index.html

the following statement is included:

"... the gravitational field carries energy and thus "attracts itself"; ..."

What does it mean?

Edit: I was made aware of the following question:  [Gravitational self-interaction](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/239093/gravitational-self-interaction). The answers given there are related, indeed. However, I would be grateful if the explanation of 'self-interaction', in general is extended to the specific meaning of 'self-attraction' of the gravitational field.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/239093/

Comment: Which article at the Gravity Probe B website? It would be helpful to provide an exact reference so we can know the context of the statement. In general though it boils down to the equations of General Relativity being non-linear.

Comment: The exact address is: https://einstein.stanford.edu/SPACETIME/spacetime3.html